# Ajax toolkit Tab Control does not work in Firefox?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using Tab control of ajax tool kit and it is working fine in IE but tabs are not being displayed in FF. I googled and found some other people had this issue. Any solution please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked [CodePlex](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/) to insure you are using the most recent version?
Also i would recommend switching to a jquery(ui) based altenative, since it's probably more robust and cross browser proof.